# Gradle, have the signing task called from (or before) the uploadArchives task

Tags: maven, jar, gradle

and a merry Good Friday to you all.
I am currently having a little issue with Gradle signing my JARs for upload to Maven central.

What I am trying to do:

- build "one" jar
- sign the "one" jar
- upload the jar and the signed jar

what I did:

- created a task to create a "one" jar
- created a new configuration
- changed the signing task to use that configuration
- changed the name of the uploadArchives task to reflect the name of the configuration.

Everything works individually, when I run uploadConfiguration it doesn't call the signing task but does upload my "one" jar.

I think the issue is how the signing task seems to be different, as it configuration is set internally rather than as a suffix to its name.

Also, coming at this from a maven background I may be trying to force Gradle to do something it isn't intended to do, something at the back of head says you probably don't need to create "one" jars as Gradle will pull in the transitive dependencies in your project when you add a dependency on a library.  Though obviously that forces maven users to make sure they have the right dependencies declared to use the library.

By "one" jar i mean the bundling of dependencies inside the libraries jar as done with the maven one-jar plugin.

Any advice or pointers would be warmly received, thank you in advance.

Comment: The term you're looking for it a "fat jar", There are plenty of examples of that online, once you know what to look for.

Comment: Yep found fatJar, that wasn't the problem, the problem was getting everything signed (the fatJar, sources and docs) and uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by:

- leaving in place the achieves configuration for artefacts
- creating a configuration
- defining a second artefacts task using my configuration containing the fatJar source and javaDoc
- configure the signing task to use my configuration
- leaving the upload task as uploadArchives

Now a double click in IntelliJ and a build is made and uploaded.